# How to get user email address in Prestashop my-account.tpl right after login?

Tags: prestashop

I'm modifying my-account.tpl in prestashop 1.4.9 and want to get user email address in this page.

However, i only have access to {$custmerName}. I've put {debug} inside and it seems it's not accessible. Also, {$smarty.post} is empty after login.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is available in the visitor's cookie, you can easily display it in my-account.tpl:

```
{l s='Your e-mail address is:'} {$cookie->email|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```

For more details, you can double-check where it is being assigned, in /controllers/AuthController.php at line 178, **upon authentication**:

```
self::$cookie->id_customer = (int)($customer->id);
self::$cookie->customer_lastname = $customer->lastname;
self::$cookie->customer_firstname = $customer->firstname;
self::$cookie->passwd = $customer->passwd;
self::$cookie->logged = 1;
self::$cookie->email = $customer->email;
```